# axios post request returning wing ding symbols

Tags: axios, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am able to successfully get a request through postman, however when i use axios to to my post request I get a status 200 but the returned data is just wing ding symbols.

here is my code for axios

```
const configAxios = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };

axios
        .post(url + 'connect/token', params, configAxios)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Here is the return value.

```
���������⌂�N▼~����O�����ӟ�Ƀ����w~������͗{�������vwg�h~v����{/⌂zQ�^�O�=�⌂p�����_�
V��O�_<]>���☼��|q��ᓋ��Y�����ߙ�8}����꧿]����^�^���}^���ç�W_�{��էg�Κ�>ث▬?�����^��N�^����I���D�;����I5����⌂�t6�>x��↨U��‼m����d{y���⌂�������~ж_�>;/�/>⌂�{7�v�[⌂�ݫ����>�����f�s���>,�]}4�(⌂�*���♂��{���>b�����UN|�$�꼦vʹ�☼�>}v�*~�Wy6���?��§('♥
```

Here is the expected results that I get from postman

```
{
    "access_token": {access_token},
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "api_read"
}
```

Comment: It's a bug in the library: https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5306. It has since been fixed and released in a new version so you can either: 1) downgrade or 2) upgrade

Comment: Yes, using axios v1.2.1

Comment: yup that did the trick thank you very much @HunterMcMillen and BenchVue

Answer (score 0):

Add `{ 'accept-encoding': '*' }` in the header.